# Why so many "removed but not purged" packages?

Tags: package-management, aptitude

Running `aptitude search '~c'` prints a whole bunch of `removed but not purged` packages, including, e.g., all kernels I have ever had installed (starting with `linux-image-3.19.0-30-generic`).

1. Why haven't they been purged?
2. How can I purge them all in a single command? 
   IOW, is

   ```
   aptitude purge $(aptitude search '~c' -F %p)
   ```

   safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They haven't been purged because there's no reason to. The kernel files left are mostly those concerning `dpkg`. There's no harm in having them around.

[As for purging them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35143/70524):

```
aptitude purge '~c'
```